# v-if implementation in ipyvuetify

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, jupyter-lab, voila

I'm quite new to using ipyvuetify and I am wondering what the best way to implement conditional rendering is. I'd like to be able to make a control disappear from the navigation sidebar when I move to another tab on my dashboard.

A simple implementation of similar behaviour would be as below:

```
import ipyvuetify as v 

button1 = v.Btn(color='red', children = ['Submit 1'], style_ = 'width:30%')
button2 = v.Btn(color='blue', children = ['Submit 2'], style_ = 'width:30%')

def on_click(widget, event, data): 
    button1.disabled = True

button2.on_event('click', on_click)

v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[button1, button2])
```

Rather than have `button1.disabled = True` when then the button is clicked, I'd like to remove/stop rendering the control all together. I figure some implementation of `v-if` would be the way to go but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the children of the button container:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v 

button1 = v.Btn(color='red', children = ['Submit 1'], style_ = 'width:30%')
button2 = v.Btn(color='blue', children = ['Submit 2'], style_ = 'width:30%')

def on_click(widget, event, data): 
    if button1 in my_buttons.children:
        my_buttons.children = [button2]
    else:
        my_buttons.children = [button1, button2]

button2.on_event('click', on_click)

my_buttons = v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[button1, button2])

my_buttons
```

Note: when changing a list or dict, always make a new instance. Mutations to an existing instance are not detected.

Comment: Great, that is much nicer. Thank you for your answer and for developing this library!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Figured out *a* way to do it but there are probably nicer ways. I update the css display property of the element in `button1.style_`.

Shown below is a way to toggle the button on and off. No doubt there are cleaner ways to do this.

```
button1 = v.Btn(color='red', children = ['Submit 1'], style_ = 'width:30%')
button2 = v.Btn(color='blue', children = ['Submit 2'], style_ = 'width:30%')

def on_click(widget, event, data): 
    
    if button1.style_ != 'display:none':
        button1.style_ = 'display:none'
    else: 
        button1.style_ = 'display:block; width:30%'
    

    
        
button2.on_event('click', on_click)

v.Html(tag='div', class_='d-flex flex-column', children=[button1, button2])
```